# Крах приложения из-за ImageButton

Tags: java, android

Проблема такова, активность крашиться при наявности в ней

```
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/newNotesButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:onClick="newNotesButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

**Виновник здесь:**

```
 android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
```

**Код rounder_button**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/black" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="4dp"
            android:left="4dp"
            android:right="4dp"
            android:top="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/black" />

        <padding

            android:bottom="18dp"
            android:left="18dp"
            android:right="18dp"
            android:top="18dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Почему идет крах? На версиях от андроид 6 до 12 все работает!

Comment: Вы хотя бы Logcat с крэшем приложили...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

исправил это заменой на кнопку **FloatingActionButton**

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:tint="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/newNotesButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:onClick="newNotesButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```